# Symfony CRUD - Forms and "View"

Tags: forms, symfony, crud

When using the Forms component in Symfony, is there a way to reuse the component or part of form the <del>"View"</del> "Read" part of CRUD.

I have created a Form Type (made simple for the purposes of this question):

```
class CustomerType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Customer Surname'))
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create'))
            ;
    }
}
```

For the "edit" part, it is easy:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_row(form.name) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

And pass the `'form' => $form->createForm()` to render.

This will generate the labels and everything from the Type definition.

However when it comes to <del>view</del> read, it seems I have to do this:

```
<span>Customer Surname</span> {{ data.name }}
```

And pass the `'data' => $customer` object to the render.

Is there any way to take the "label" part of the form Type and use this when creating the <del>"view"</del> "read" template so when I update the label it changes on both the <del>"view"</del> "read" and the "update" parts?

Forms seem very useful, especially with features like Data Transformation, but it seems a bit of duplication of code between the "update" and the <del>"view"</del> "read".

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use translations.

In form:

```
->add('name',TextType::class, array('label' => 'form.name'))
```

In views - `form/form_label.html.twig`

```
{% block form_label %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <label for="{{ id }}">{{ id|replace({'_':'.'})|trans }}</label>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_label %}
```

In `config.yml`

```
framework:
    translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
twig:
    form_themes:
        - 'form/form_label.html.twig'
```

In any view you can use

```
{{ 'form.name'|trans }}
```

But try no assign any label, then you can use default label generated as:

```
< name of bundle >_< name of class >_< name of property >
```

Of course you should also define translations. I assume, that you know how to use translations. If not, look to docs:

> https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/usage.html

Update - extended answer

Example of messages.yml

1) if you want to create labels manually and use {{ 'form.name'|trans }}

```
form:
    name: 'Customer Name'
```

2) if you want to no write boilerplate, (I preferring this way)

```
 app:
     customer:
         name: 'Customer Name'
```

I assumed that your bundle has name AppBundle, your class has name Customer. You can use now string 'Customer Name' in "Read" part of crud:

```
<span>{{'app.customer.name'|trans}}</span>{{customer.name}}
```

and in form it will be added automatically, so there is enough to have

```
{{form_start(form)}}
{{form_rest(form)}}
<input type="sumbit" name="Create/update - or translations of these words">
{{form_end(form)}}
```

There is good practice, to write forms in this way, and do no append `sumbit` to form definition. It allows to easier build nested forms in future and create one form for created and edit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Daniel, however I'm not sure this answers what I was trying to ask. When I say "view" I actually mean "read", as in how you would normally just display data from an entity.

Comment: I understand that You want to write `Customer Surname` only in one place in your code. If yes, then translations are the most pure way to achieve this. If you want to have as really small amount of code, then do not set label in form. Will be created automatically as e.g `app_customer_name`, then in form_label.html.twig it is transformed to tranlation of `app.customer.name`. Next you should add translations and you can use {{ 'app.customer.name' }} in any view - in read, update, delete, and create part of crud.